# get the random key from firebase database in ionic 4

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic4

I'm trying to get the random key that is generated when I add data under "Course" to Firebase. I'm using ionic 4 for my application.

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/xq7GL.jpg

in the code bellow, inside the onSubmit function, the last two lines:
i had one variable that holds the the UID of the user called "currentUser", and another variable that should hold the key of the data added "datakey". I'm not sure what should be the complete code for the "dataKey" variable so that I can get the key of the data added.

Any help ?

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router,ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { FirebaseService } from '../services/firebase.service';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-subjects',
    templateUrl: './subjects.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['./subjects.page.scss'],
})
export class SubjectsPage implements OnInit {

    subject_form: FormGroup;
    subjects: Array<any>;
    gradeArray: number[]=[];
    creditHourArray: number[]=[];
    creditHourTot: number=0;
    gpaDisplay: number;
    dataKey: string;


    constructor(
        private authService: AuthService,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private firebaseService: FirebaseService,
        private router: Router,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
        public afs: AngularFirestore,

    ) { }
    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.route && this.route.data) {
            this.getData();
          }
          this.resetFields();

        }

        async getData(){
                this.route.data.subscribe(routeData => {
                  routeData['data'].subscribe(data => {
                    this.subjects = data;
                  })
                })
              }

              async presentLoading(loading) {
                return await loading.present();
              }

    resetFields() {
        this.subject_form = this.formBuilder.group({
            subName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            subCode: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            creditHour: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            grade: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
        });
    }

    onSubmit(value) {

        this.gradeArray.push(value.grade)
        this.creditHourArray.push(value.creditHour)
        let data = {
            subName: value.subName,
            subCode: value.subCode,
            creditHour: value.creditHour,
            grade: value.grade,
        }


        this.creditHourTot= this.creditHourTot + value.creditHour;




        this.firebaseService.createSubjects(data,this.gradeArray,this.creditHourArray)
        this.firebaseService.createGPA(this.gradeArray,this.creditHourArray)
        this.gpaDisplay = this.firebaseService.calGPA(this.gradeArray,this.creditHourArray)
        console.log(this.gpaDisplay);

        let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser
        let dataKey = this.afs.collection('people').doc(currentUser.uid).collection('Course')

    }

    goToSemPage() {
        this.router.navigate(["/semesters"]);
    }

    goToSubListPage(){
      this.router.navigate(["/subject-list"]);
    }


    logout() {
        this.authService.doLogout()
            .then(res => {
                this.router.navigate(["/home"]);
            }, err => {
                console.log(err);
            })
    }
}
```

this is the code of my method "createSubjects"

```js
  createSubjects(value,gradeArray,creditHourArray) {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {

      let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser; 

      this.afs.collection('people').doc(currentUser.uid).collection('Course').add({
        subName: value.subName,
        subCode: value.subCode,
        creditHour: value.creditHour,
        grade: value.grade
        gpa: this.calGPA(gradeArray,creditHourArray)
      })

      .then(
          res => resolve(res),
          err => reject(err)
      )

    })
  }
```

UPDATE: The new "onSubmit" method:

```js
onSubmit(value) {

        this.gradeArray.push(value.grade)
        this.creditHourArray.push(value.creditHour)
        let data = {
            subName: value.subName,
            subCode: value.subCode,
            creditHour: value.creditHour,
            grade: value.grade,
        }


        this.creditHourTot= this.creditHourTot + value.creditHour;

        this.firebaseService.createSubjects(data,this.gradeArray,this.creditHourArray).then(
            (val) => { this.datakey = val.id }
        );
        this.firebaseService.createGPA(this.gradeArray,this.creditHourArray)
        this.gpaDisplay = this.firebaseService.calGPA(this.gradeArray,this.creditHourArray)

        console.log(val);

        // let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser
        // let datakey = this.afs.collection('people').doc(currentUser.uid).collection('Course')

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure of my understanding of your use-case.

I assume your method "createSubjects" is the one in which you make your calls to firebase to create "Course".

So you need to return a promise in your method "createSubject",

if createSubject returns directly a firebase promise then you just need to:

```
this.firebaseService.createSubjects(data,this.gradeArray,this.creditHourArray).then(
    (val) => { this.datakey = val.id }
);
```

edit: I changed 'key' to 'id' , key is what you get on firebase, on firestore 'id' is used.

Comment: I tried to adjust the line, and print out the value of datakey on the console, it shows that the value is undefined. I'v adjusted the question to contain the code of the method "createSubject".

Comment: Instead of looking at what datakey is, you should have looked at what "  (val)  " variable contains : 

you can see by typing : console.log(val);
within the two brackets

Comment: I did that .. and an error saying "Cannot find name 'val': Did you mean eval?" has appeared .. I've adjusted the question to contain the new code for "onSubmit" method.

Comment: Hiyou need to console between the { } of the  .then()

Comment: Hey .. that didn't work too .. the same error "Cannot find name 'val': Did you mean eval?" is  still showing up, and a new error is showing now "Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(reason: any) => PromiseLike<never>'."

Comment: ... I do not think you did the right thing :

        this.firebaseService.createSubjects(data,this.gradeArray,this.creditHourArray).then(
            (val) => { console.log(val) ; this.datakey = val.id }
        );

Doing so will show you if your promise returns sth, and allows you to locate your error.